# How to populate dependency list on init?

Tags: angular

I have two selects where second depend on first one. I want to get populated both of them. This is my selects:

```
 <div class="z-inputs no-border">
                        <div class="z-selecticon no-border">
                            <select [ngModel]="orderTracking.destinationfromCode" (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)" (click)="selectItemForRequest(orderTracking);selectGroup(orderTracking.destinationfromCode);">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option *ngFor="let destination of groupDestinations" [ngValue]="destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>    
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-g-1 no-border">
                        <div class="z-inputs no-border">
                            <div class="z-selecticon no-border">
                                <select  [(ngModel)]="orderTracking.destinationtoCode">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option *ngFor="let destination of destinationsTo" [ngValue]="destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

In this case only first one is populated, and when i click on first one then it populate second. I tried (change) to replace with (click) but i have same problem. Any suggestion?

This is my ts:

```
 getGroupDestitantion(): void {
        let path: string = '/uomback/rdestinationgroup/code-displayname';
        this.restService.get(path).subscribe(response => {
            this.groupDestinations = response['payload'];;
        })
    }
    selectGroup(group) {
        this.selectedGroup = group;
        group && this.getDestinationTo();
    }
    getDestinationTo() {

        let path: string = '/uomback/rdestination/rdestidation-groupCode-orditemnum';
        let groupdestination = this.selectedGroup;
        let request = { orditemnum: this.selectedOrderTracking.orditemnum, groupdestination: groupdestination };
        this.restService.get(path, request).subscribe(response => {
            this.destinationsTo = response['payload'];
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please include more relevant code. Code is supposed to be **minimal** reproduction of the problem. Here all I see is irrelevant markup.

Comment: i added code also from ts. I dont know what else to include?

Comment: Please create a reproduction. You have not included any _call_ to these functions. If you want something to happen during initialization of a component, call that function in `OnInit` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Example to react to select change and load a other list specific on the selected option.

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mot6va)